# Is Powershell the same as terminal on a mac machine?

Tags: ubuntu, powershell, terminal

I used terminal on the ubuntu os and now I saw powershell on Windows 7.
Before going into powershell I want to know if powershell is the same as 
the terminal on ubuntu and mac, or do I have to learn more and new syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very similar *concept*, but they're completely different environments with regard to syntax, style & workflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are some aliases (such as ls) in powershell that are there to make it a little easier for someone coming from a *nix background, but in reality you will have to learn a whole new set of syntax and commands.

Comment: Cygwin. There are some shell ports out there too.